# Find Max & Min of one column and difference of two other columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a table named **kpi** where I need to calculate the difference of (B1 - B0) for each BoxID per week using the Minimum **No.** and Maximum **No.** for each BoxID per week -

I couldn't calculate the **First_b1, Last_b0 and Diff**

```
kpi <- kpi %>%
        mutate(weekNumber = week(dmy(Date))) %>% 
        group_by(SolboxID, weekNumber) %>%
        arrange(SolboxID)

**Date      No.   BoxID B0      B1      WkNo**
29.10.2018  61931   1   0       0       44
15.11.2018  115763  1   5.38    5.38    46
16.11.2018  119833  1   51.86   52.23   46
29.10.2018  60486   3   23.26   22.97   44
10.11.2018  99576   3   1336.53 1336.53 45
14.11.2018  112259  3   1.19    1.04    46
16.11.2018  117965  3   8.68    47.22   46
16.11.2018  118092  3   47.22   47.22   46
15.11.2018  115396  4   82.05   82.05   46
```

Expected output table -

```
Date        No.   BoxID B0      B1      WkNo   First_b1     Last_b0  Diff
29.10.2018  61931   1   0       0       44     0            0        0
15.11.2018  115763  1   5.38    5.38    46     52.23        5.38     46.85
16.11.2018  119833  1   51.86   52.23   46     52.23        5.38     46.85
29.10.2018  60486   3   23.26   22.97   44     22.97        23.26    -0.29
10.11.2018  99576   3   1336.53 1336.53 45     1336.53      1336.53  0
14.11.2018  112259  3   1.19    1.04    46     47.22        1.19     46.03
16.11.2018  117965  3   8.68    47.22   46     47.22        1.19     46.03
16.11.2018  118092  3   47.22   47.22   46     47.22        1.19     46.03
15.11.2018  115396  4   82.05   82.05   46     82.05       82.05     0
```

I need some help to compute the 3 more columns. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple pipe seems to do the job. See if this is it.

```
library(tidyverse)

kpi %>%
  group_by(BoxID, WkNo) %>%
  mutate(i = which.min(No.), 
         j = which.max(No.)) %>%
  mutate(First_B0 = B0[i],
         Last_B1 = B1[j],
         Diff = Last_B1 - First_B0) %>%
  select(-i, -j)
## A tibble: 9 x 9
## Groups:   BoxID, WkNo [6]
#  Date        No. BoxID      B0     B1  WkNo First_B0 Last_B1   Diff
#  <fct>     <int> <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 29.10.2…  61931     1    0    0.        44     0        0     0   
#2 15.11.2… 115763     1    5.38 5.38e0    46     5.38    52.2  46.8 
#3 16.11.2… 119833     1   51.9  5.22e1    46     5.38    52.2  46.8 
#4 29.10.2…  60486     3   23.3  2.30e1    44    23.3     23.0  -0.29
#5 10.11.2…  99576     3 1337.   1.34e3    45  1337.    1337.    0   
#6 14.11.2… 112259     3    1.19 1.04e0    46     1.19    47.2  46.0 
#7 16.11.2… 117965     3    8.68 4.72e1    46     1.19    47.2  46.0 
#8 16.11.2… 118092     3   47.2  4.72e1    46     1.19    47.2  46.0 
#9 15.11.2… 115396     4   82.0  8.20e1    46    82.0     82.0   0
```

**Data.**

```
kpi <- read.table(text = "
Date      No.   BoxID B0      B1      WkNo
29.10.2018  61931   1   0       0       44
15.11.2018  115763  1   5.38    5.38    46
16.11.2018  119833  1   51.86   52.23   46
29.10.2018  60486   3   23.26   22.97   44
10.11.2018  99576   3   1336.53 1336.53 45
14.11.2018  112259  3   1.19    1.04    46
16.11.2018  117965  3   8.68    47.22   46
16.11.2018  118092  3   47.22   47.22   46
15.11.2018  115396  4   82.05   82.05   46                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: No. Min Max of the B0, B1 value is not the thing. Need to use the minimum value of No. and use the corresponding B0 and use the max value of No. and use the corresponding B1, then find the difference.

Comment: @FarahNazifa See if the edit does it. Also, you should edit the question with that comment to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rui. Can you please help me write the same code in Python please? I would be really grateful to you.

Comment: @FarahNazifa That is a different question. You should ask a question and tag it `python`. `R` programmers do not necessarily know Python.